# image file on external HDD cannot be read and transferred to another drive - created using macrium reflect

Tags: windows-8.1, external-hard-drive, file-transfer, ubuntu-14.04, macrium

I have created a image backup using macrium reflect - it succussfully completed. I can explore the windows partition.

The file is on an external 1TB hard drive. The backup is 105GB in size. Contains ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8.1. 9 Partitions.

The problem is I cannot transfer the file on the external drive to another external one, or the internal one for that matter. I want to upload to cloud storage eventually. I don't want to try that until I can transfer locally however.

The transfer gets to 5GB out of the 105GB - then transfer rate drops to 0 Bytes a second. The error says cannot read source file or disk.

Can anyone advise?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the external drive enclosure is going to sleep or windows has sent a command to spin down the drive.

Answer (score 0):

I could not resolve the problem. I did however find an alternative to the backup software.

Instead of Macrium Reflect I use Paragon Backup and Restore Home Free. Both free products offered by the two different companies. Paragon by default split the files into 4GB chunks and I was able to transfer these files between hard drives and upload to cloud storage.